# Redirecting persistent HTTP requests and responses using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, stream

I wish to create a router of some sort to redirect HTTP requests from an HTTP client to a servlet (they preform a negotation process. More background: I wish to do an auth from windows to windows server, going throug a redirective Unix web server).

My servlet is on `http://localhost:8080`
and my redirector is on `8081`

So, I wrote this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Redirect {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8081);
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
        Socket l = ss.accept();
        l.setKeepAlive(true);
        s.setKeepAlive(true);
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = l.getInputStream();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyReader(is, os,"#1"));
        t1.start();
        InputStream is2 = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os2 = l.getOutputStream();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyReader(is2, os2,"#2"));
        t2.start();
    }

    public static class MyReader implements Runnable {
        private InputStream _i;
        private OutputStream _o;
        private String _id;

        public MyReader(InputStream i, OutputStream o, String id) {
            _i = i;
            _o = o;
            _id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int x;
                x = _i.read();
                while (x != -1) {
                    System.out.println(_id);
                    _o.write(x);
                    _o.flush();
                    x = _i.read();
                }
                System.out.println(x);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for most servlets! So what's my problem? My servlet is a persistent one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection, that is it does connection=keep-alive and does a whole back and forth messaging dance.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I could run two MyReader threads and that they will block until new information comes, but instead they keep blocking.

This is my client:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8081/Abc/Def");
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        huc.setDoOutput(true);
        huc.connect();
        InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();//The all auth process is done here
             //and HttpUrlConnection support it. If I change 8081 to 8080, it works

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding an infinite wait loop after starting t2 thread as shown below

```
              while ( true) {
                  sleep(1000);
              }
```